# -[UITableView setStyle:] in iOS 6 crashing the app (but not in iOS 5.1)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, ios5.1

For some reasons we have situations when we have to set properties from a `NSDictionary` to an `UIView`.
Everything was OK 'till the iOS 6 was released. Now `-[UITableView setValue:value forKey:@"style"]` is crashing the app. In iOS 6 it calls `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` but in iOS 5.1 it doesn't (and everything is OK then). I know that `style` `UITableView`'s property is read-only but... why? I have my own implementation of `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` but I don't want to filter somehow such properties (it'll be difficult to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that style UITableView's property is read-only but... why?

Because Apple decided to be so, and they probably have a pretty good reason for it. Don't try setting readonly properties, they will crash your app.

Comment: It's probably read-only because the style determines a lot of layout and view setup... which is difficult to do multiple times per cell.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's ok, but I just have read the changelist and there is no info about this "feature". And about backgrounds of grouped tables too. Is there a full changelist somewhere? I don't even know what I will find next time.

Comment: @efpies the thing is that Apple doesn't have to indicate this change. This property was always readonly, and it seems that it was just a private feature that it could be set using KVC.